# While loop query in python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Hi I would like some explanation to the below code.

1.

```
command = ''
while command = "quit":
    command = input('>')
    print('ECHO',command)
```

File "", line 2
while command = "quit":
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When I run the same code with a != 'quit' :
the program runs
2.

```
command = ''
while command != "quit":
    command = input('>')
    print('ECHO',command)
```

3. 

```
command = ''
while command == "quit":
    command = input('>')
    print('ECHO',command)
```

I would like to know why the 1st code is getting the error while the 2nd is running and why the 3rd code is not getting the dialog box to enter the input.

Answer (score 1):

1. `=` means assignment, not equality test. This can not be used in `if` condition.
2. `!=` is an inequality test, so the loop will run until "quit" is entered.
3. `==` is an equality test. The loop will never run.